# Working/Having worked at Google helped me land a job. - what are the differences?

Tags: gerunds, time-words

**Example 1**

> Working at Google helped me land a job.

**Example 2**

> Having worked at Google helped me land a job.

One is "Working" and the other is "Having worked."

What are the differences?

The following is what I think:

Example 1:
The event of working at Google and the event of helping me land a job happened at the same time.
In other words, it sounds like I got a new offer while I was working at Google.

Example 2:
It sounds like the event of working at Google happened first and maybe a few years passed, and then the event of helping me land a job happened.

I don't know whether my understanding makes sense. Please tell me what you think.

**Example 3**

> Working at Google 5 years ago allowed me to land a job last year.

What about adding time adverbs?

Does Example 3 mean the event of working at Google happened first (5 years ago) and then I left Google, and then the experience of working at Google helped me land a job last year?

Do you think my interpretation makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically correct.

Gerunds are untensed, so in example 1 the reader can not be sure of when the "working" happened. However, most people will probably assume that it happened at the same time as the helping.

In example 2, the gerund phrase ("having worked") is in the perfect aspect, indicating that it happened earlier, i.e., before the helping.

In example 3, the times are explicit, so there is no question about when the events occurred. However, I wouldn't assume that the writer "left Google". It is possible, for example, that the writer worked for Google from 2016 to 2021, Google launched a new product in 2017, and working on that product helped the speaker to land a new job in 2021.

Comment: I generally agree, though example 2 sounds somewhat ambiguous to me. "Having worked at Google" could be in the past relative to the time the statement is made, but not necessarily in the past relative to the helping. The ambiguity is more obvious if you change the sentence just a bit: "Having worked at Google for a year helped me land a job."

Comment: @cruthers But if it weren't in the past relative to the helping, then how could it have helped? I agree that on grammatical grounds there may be some ambiguity, but on semantic grounds I think that only one interpretation is possible.

Comment: @MarcInManhatten - what I meant was that "Having worked at Google for a year helped me land a job" could mean that the work at Google was ongoing when the (next) job was landed. If you remove "for a year" from the sentence, it could conceivably mean the same thing, albeit without specifying the length of time. In either case it could also mean that the work at Google had already been completed by the time the next job was landed. Ambiguous in both cases, I think.

Comment: @cruthers Oh yes, I agree that "having worked" doesn't specify whether the working was still ongoing or not. We only know that at least some of the working occurred earlier.